# Как правильно сделать json в c#?

Tags: c#, json

Сейчас делаю json кодом

> var v = new
>             {
>                 token = token, 
>                 method = "abc", 
>                 param = new string[1] { "data: [nokia]"},
>                 locale = "ru"
>             };
>
> ```
>         json = jss.Serialize( v );
> ```

Получаю:

> {"token":"test","method":"abc","param":["data:
> [nokia]"],"locale":"ru"}

А нужно получить json  с `"param": {"data": ["nokia"]}`

> { "locale": "ru", "token": "test",
> "method": "abc",  "param": {"data":
> ["nokia"]} }

Не правильно формируется `"param": {"data": ["nokia"]}`. Что необходимо корректировать в коде?

Comment: А если string[1] убрать?

Comment: Неявное преобразование типа "AnonymousType#1"

Answer (score 2):

```
var v = new
{
    token = token,
    method = "abc",
    locale = "ru",
    param = new
    {
        data = new[] { "nokia" }
    }
};
```

Судя по вашему описанию, `param` - это объект внутри объекта, в котором есть поле-массив.

Comment: вопрос закрыт, решили, благодарю

Comment: @prog432, если "вопрос закрыт" - закройте его.

Comment: где эта кнопка?